# Error when reading metadata: INVALID_TYPE: This type of metadata is not available for this organization

Tags: metadata-api, error-messages

I am trying to get a list of all metadata objects with the given name. However, the code below fails:

```
connection.readMetadata("ApexClass", new String[] {"SampleDeployClass"});
```

with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException: INVALID_TYPE: This type of metadata is not available for this organization
```

Using `connection.listMetadata()` I am able to confirm that `SampleDeployClass` exists. I'm using a DE org, and the user has the *Modify all data* permission.

Is this something expexted (couldn't find it in the docs)? If yes, how am I able to confirm that a set of metadata objects already exists (other than [retrieve()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieve.htm))?

**UPDATE 1:**

Seems like [renameMetadata()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_renameMetadata.htm) doesn't work with ApexClasses either. Is it maybe a restriction in the API which prevents anyone from changing Apex code?

**UPDATE 2:**

Nor does it work using [JSForce](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#metadata-api), so it's not something related to the client code.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I've been banging my head against this as well.

Comment: @Rockdocta Nope, no answer here. I ended up using `retrieve()` as a workaround, but what I initially wanted to accomplish, I haven't.

Comment: Can you post here what your retrieve code looks like?

Comment: Basically, it's this: https://gist.github.com/hariso/f01552019fcd05fd4835#file-retrievemetadata-java

Comment: I've been facing same kind of error, I'm trying to ReadMetadata only (ApexTrigger), but it return same error even in DE or Sandbox org. Does anyone know why? I'm not trying to update Trigger, I am only trying to read them.

Comment: Same issue here in 2020, no resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Tooling API instead.

I'm using JSForce for this.

```
connection.tooling.sobject('ApexClass').retrieve('01p7R000007Axk8QAC', (error, result) => {
   
});
```